# Would you prefer coding PHP using a framework or on its own?

Tags: php

Would you prefer coding PHP using a framework or just PHP? I started using CodeIgniter and now I am back to just PHP for my clients' projects.

Comment: I think there are a few questions quite like this and quite recently too :)

Comment: even if this didn't have duplicates, this should be in community wiki. preference questions have no right and wrong answers

Comment: Community wiki does not make subjective questions magically on-topic. This is a question that belongs on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: So instead of talking about it, close or relocate the question.

Answer (score 2):

Answer is quite simple, if you can manage the project in flat php then go for it if not then select whatever suitable framework.

Answer (score 1):

Another situation where using a framework is really helpful is when developing a larger site with many people involved.

Having rules for how to write and document stuff becomes very important as project complexity increases, and a framework which implements DRY and Convention over configuration principles can be a real life saver as projects grow.

That being said, it all depends on preference and needs. If you work by yourself, or a small team, and are fairly experienced and structured, you might not need the structure a framework offers.

And if performance is a **real** issue in your application there can be a significant overhead using frameworks.

But often it is my experience that skepticism towards frameworks is rooted in incompetence.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use a decent framework for any language IF the project is large enough. Some frameworks introduce dependencies. So if it's small or should be small, then I will not use a framework.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a fairly large project and we're building on top of the CakePHP framework.
Its easier to do some of the major tasks, such as pretty URL's, database access etc.
The frameworks do introduce a overhead, and it makes it harder to move to a different platform.
Right now, I'm more inclined to work with vanilla PHP, because I feel it would be easier to code and optimize, because I know what its doing in the backend and its easier to optimize.
I think I'd use the frameworks in places where I need more features quickly, and am not too worried about execution speed.